#  How to create complex datatype for column with spaces in the name?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a stored procedure that returns columns with spaces and dashes in the column names.  I cannot simply use the "Get Column Information" button to automatically generate a complex type for this stored procedure.

How do I handle the spaces and dashes in the field names since they are not legal characters for field names in C#?

Comment: can you modify the stored procedure? if not, can you create a wrapper stored procedure that calls the procedure and then returns the results with different column names?

Comment: I am asking this question because I cannot modify the stored procedure.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to this.

Go ahead and create the complex type substituting underscores for spaces in the column names or follow whatever convention you like naming the fields in the complex type.

Then, click on your function import in the Model Browser.  At the bottom of the Visual Studio 2010 window, there should be a tab that says "Mapping Details".  Here, you can specify the name of the column that corresponds to each field in your complex type.  Type in the column names with the spaces here.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use a `SqlDataAdapter` to execute the stored procedure. You can then use the `Fill` method which will store the contents into a `DataSet` in which you can then iterate through the rows. This works with columns that have spaces. Please refer to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38019533/4896260) for a detailed solution on this.