# How to call stored procedure that returns columns with spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to call a stored procedure using entity 6.0. After looking to these solutions [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/column-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077865/how-to-create-complex-datatype-for-column-with-spaces-in-the-name/10080489#10080489), they didn't solve the problem. The issue is that one of the returned columns has a spaces in it (I'm unable to change the stored procedure). I've have tried the following with no success:

MyModel.cs

```
using System;
...

namespace ...
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        public string id{ get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Number Of ID")]
        [Column("Number Of ID")]
        public int number_Of_ID { get; set; }

    }

    public class MyModelContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

MyController.cs

```
using System;
...

namespace ...
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        private MyEntities db = new MyEntities ();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var query = @"exec usp_getIds";

            var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<MyModel>(query);
            return View(results);
        }
    }
```

When debugging the code, my model has a value for `id` but not for `number_Of_ID`. The value is always 0. I've also tried changing the datatype to a `string` and it returns `null`. Please help.

Comment: If the number_of_ID can be spaces, make the field in the model a string - that way, the number will come back, and you can cast it in the code that uses it after validating that it is a number.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried using a string and it returns `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was not able to use a `DBContext`, I found a solution using `SQLDataAdapter`. I was able to make the call successfully even with columns that had spaces. The following was changed in the controller:

MyController.cs

```
using System;
...

namespace ...
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {   
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var myResultsList = new List<MyModel>();
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myDBConn"];
            var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string query = @"usp_getIds";
            using (var sqlAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
            {
                sqlAdpt.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                var results = new DataSet();
                sqlAdpt.Fill(results);
                myResultsList= results.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().
                Select(dataRow => new MyModel
                    {
                        id = dataRow.Field<string>("ID"),
                        numberOfID = dataRow.Field<int>("Number Of ID")
                    }).ToList();

            }
            return View(myResultsList);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean there are spaces in a column name or in a value?

For a stored procedure usp_getIds, you should be able to do:

```
List<usp_getIds_Result> results = db.usp_getIds().ToList();
```

The class `usp_getIds_Result` is automatically created when you add the procedure to the model.

See if it helps to try this.